# delete an object from Coredata (getting an error)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I try to delete an object from coredata which matches with `Test2`. I tried this:

```
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = Test2")
    var error : NSError?
    let results = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error)

    context.deleteObject(results.firstObject as NSManagedObject)
```

I get an error in this line of code: `context.deleteObject(results.firstObject as NSManagedObject)`. It says: `Cannot invoke 'deleteObject' with an argument list of type '(NSManagedObject)'`. Does someone knows how I can solve this error?

UPDATE:

```
2015-07-12 20:43:09.601 Note[4222:138125] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (name == Test2) (problem on RHS)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebd6c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110741bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreData                            0x000000010e7f0bbc -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 1724
3   CoreData                            0x000000010e7dcdc4 -[NSSQLAdapter _statementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 244
4   CoreData                            0x000000010e6f4e0c -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 316
5   CoreData                            0x000000010e6f4a86 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 118
6   CoreData                            0x000000010e6f433c -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 524
7   CoreData                            0x000000010e6f3dbb -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 299
8   CoreData                            0x000000010e7cea6c __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3356
9   CoreData                            0x000000010e7d7c30 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 192
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111e65614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111e4b002 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365
12  CoreData                            0x000000010e7c9245 _perform + 197
13  CoreData                            0x000000010e6f3a58 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504
14  CoreData                            0x000000010e6f22ca -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 586
15  Note                               0x000000010e4efb72 _TFC5Note14ViewController19deleteSelectedTasksfS0_FT_T_ + 738
16  Note                               0x000000010e4ef843 _TFC5Note14ViewController7delTaskfS0_FT_T_ + 51
17  Note                               0x000000010e4ef882 _TToFC5Note14ViewController7delTaskfS0_FT_T_ + 34
18  Foundation                          0x000000010f011744 __NSFireTimer + 83
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eb3e174 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eb3dd35 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eaffd3d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eaff366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011128ca3e GSEventRunModal + 161
24  UIKit                               0x000000010f475900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
25  Note                                0x000000010e5146c7 main + 135
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111e99145 start + 1
27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your predicate definition. Please try:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = 'Test2'")
```

or

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "name", "Test2")
```

If you want to add a variable.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "name", variable)
```

Comment: Yes the first one finally worked. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I marked it as correct. Could you please tell me what I have to write if I wanna replace `Test2` for a string-variable? `(format: "name = '\(variable)'")` doesn't work.

Comment: Please find my answer edited. I also recommend you this post http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `context.deleteObject(results?.first as! NSManagedObject)` and it will compile but it will crash if it's not a NSManagedObject.

This is obviously not the right approach. Remember: `!` are code smells, because in most of the cases you don't need them.

`firstObject` is a NSArray method, to use it you should specify that `results` is of type `NSArray` (i.e. `let results: NSArray`). The Swift standard library equivalent is `first`, and returns an optional value while `deleteObject` doesn't accept an optional. So you should unwrap it and you can check if it is of type `NSManagedObject` at the same time.

What about something like:

```
   if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error),
      let managedObject = results.first as? NSManagedObject {
         context.deleteObject(managedObject)
   }
```

Comment: I tried out your proposal. Now I the app crashes in this line of code: `if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error),` with the following error: `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2 3.2`. Here are a few (hopefully) useful images: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ubnlnufodnsb2l/Bildschirmfoto%202015-07-12%20um%2019.27.06.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/5m9vdx2tlgns59o/Bildschirmfoto%202015-07-12%20um%2019.28.18.png?dl=0. Hope it helps to solve the error.

Comment: It seems like you have set some breakpoints in your code rather than an error. Please disable your breakpoints and it should work.

Comment: I set an exception breakpoint. I disabled it but the app is still crashing. Now I also get an log entry (see my updated answer). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @agy Do you know what I have to do?

Comment: @paro find my answer posted